# How to specify page url in jquery ajax call from Master Page in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, master-pages

I am trying to call a webmethod from Master Page in my asp.net project and almost succeeded. In my solution explorer "Master Page" and "MyService.asmx" is in root folder but content pages are inside a folder let's say "Admin" folder. So when I go to page "Admin/firstcontent.aspx " I have to specify the url in Master Page like this

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../MyService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
```

But when I go to page "Admin/Master/secondcontent.aspx" I have to specify url like this

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../MyService.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
```

**Second Problem:-** In every content page I must have to call jquery.min inside head section.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is I create a global javascript variable in the Master page e.g `window.applicationBaseUrl='<%= Url.Content("~/")' %>'` and use it in every sub-page like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.applicationBaseUrl + "MyService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```

Relative paths may get screwed when you deploy your application to IIS.

Comment: what is Url here ?

Comment: UrlHelper class, inside System.Web.Mvc

Comment: I am not using MVC

Comment: Then try using Request.ApplicationPath

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define your root path of application  like

```
 var rootpath="www.yourdomainname.com" or "localhost:8080"
```

and  after use rootpath variable and call your method

```
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
           url: rootpath + "MyService.asmx/HelloWorld",
          data: '{}',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

try this . thanks